# Can't limit panning area of Scrollview inside CollectionViewCell

Tags: scrollview, limit, pan

I have some images and i open them in CollectionView, its like an album, user can swipe left and right and can pinch zoom. I use a scrollview inside the cell and an image inside the scrollview

My problem is when i pinch zoom image zooms, but after that when i navigate on the image, it goes up and down too much, i want to limit navigation on he picture frame, but i couldnt manage to do it, tried everything, searched a lot, but couldnt able to do it, so i wanted to ask you.

You can see the image below and understand what i mean better.

http://s8.postimg.org/oypni96id/image.png

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class SlideViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var images = ["image1.jpg" , "image2.jpg" , "image3.jpg" , "image1.jpg" , "image2.jpg" , "image3.jpg" , "image1.jpg" , "image2.jpg" , "image3.jpg" , "image1.jpg"]
    var flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        var scrollView:UIScrollView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIScrollView
        var image:UIImageView = scrollView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
        self.flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
        self.flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
        self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.flowLayout, animated: true)
        image.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let frame = view.frame

        return CGSizeMake(frame.width, frame.height)
    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        var image:UIImageView = scrollView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView

        return image
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var scrollView:UIScrollView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIScrollView
        scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be closed, i used MWPhotoBrowser gallery instead of solving this problem. Thank you anyway ;)